# Mission Control view programme icons missing. How can I get them back?

Tags: macos, icon, mission-control

When you hit F3 on the keyboard, Mission Control is opening, displaying all active windows in a miniaturized version neatly ordererd. When my Mac OSX 10.8 was newly installed some month ago, there were programme icons displayed together with every mini window in Mission Control. How can I get these icons back?

This is how my Mission Control looks like:
[image: mission control view without programme icons]

This is how it is supposed to look like, with programme icons:
[image: mission control view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the "Group windows by application" option turned off – this tiles every window individually so that nothing overlaps (this is how Exposé used to work in OS X 10.5 Leopard and earlier).

When "Group windows by application" is on, the tiled windows are stacked in groups based on which application they belong to, and the application icon is overlaid on the group, as in your second screenshot.

To enable "Group windows by application", go to the Apple menu > System Preferences > Mission Control and check the box.